# bigtable bulk update based on dynamic filter

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm looking for a way to scan huge Google BigTable with filter dynamically composed based on the events and make bulk update/delete on huge numbers of rows.

At the moment, I'm trying to combine BigTable with java-based Dataflow (for intensive serverless compute power).  I reached to the point where I can compose "Scan" object with dynamic filter based on the events but I still can't find a way to stream results from CloudBigtableIO.read() to subsequent dataflow pipeline.

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Extend your DoFn from [AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/dataflow-hbase-api/javadoc/com/google/cloud/bigtable/dataflow/AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn).  That will give you access to a getConnection() method.  You'll do something like this:

```
try(Connection c = getConnection();
    Table t = c.getTable(YOUR_TABLE_NAME);
    ResultScanner resultScanner = t.getScanner(YOUR_SCAN)) {
  for(Result r : resultScanner) {
     Mutation m = ... // construct a Put or Delete
     context.output(m)
  }
}
```

I'm assuming that your pipeline starts with `CloudBigtableIO.read()`, has the `AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn` next, and then has a `CloudBigtableIO.write()`.